# Parameterized pages not setting titles, am I doing this properly?

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

If you go to the blog directly and click a tag to filter, routes, page titles are set
https://www.sitefinitysteve.com/blog

If you navigate directly to the page, nothing is set...
https://www.sitefinitysteve.com/blog/tag/tutorial

I'm changing the blog titles in /pages/blog/index.vue -> asyncData depending if I see a tag or pager in the params.  But that doesn't seem to get triggered on direct load, however the /pages/blog/tag/_tag.vue -> asyndData does trigger, but adding it there seems to override /pages/blog/index.vue->asyncData so I'd have to re-implement just everything.

```
<script lang="ts">
import BlogIndex from '../index.vue';

export default {
  extends: BlogIndex,

};
</script>
```

Am I just missing something super obvious? SHOULD I be re-implementing everything in _tag.vue?

**EDIT**
Literally copy\pasting /index.vue to _tag.vue and _pages.vue seems to make everying okay, but I hate doing this fundamentally on so many levels.  So it's pushed to prod now so the above links should look fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding from '../../index.vue'